# valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Have been facing issue while iterating through a list and printing elements in React.

The React Code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FetchData} from '../actions/data';

class DataList extends Component{
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchData('http://somedomain/api/tweets');
}
renderList(){
    return this.props.data.map((i) => (
        <li  key={i.id} >
            {i.body}
        </li>
    ) )
}
render(){
if (this.props.hasErrored){
        return console.log('sorry there was an error');
    }else if (this.props.isLoading){
        return console.log('Loadings...');
    }else {
     if(this.props.data.length){
         return (
           <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
         );
     }
}
}
   }

DataList.propTypes = {
fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  };

   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
    data: state.data,
    hasErrored: state.dataHasErrored,
    isLoading: state.dataIsLoading
   };
      };

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
    fetchData: (url) => dispatch(FetchData(url))
    };
     };

     export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DataList);
```

And I'm getting an error of:

> DataList.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

I'm pretty sure there is some issue with returns in the render function of the Not sure what is the issue though.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: `<li>` is invalid child of `<div>` in html

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` returns `undefined`, which is not "A valid React element (or null)".

Replace those calls with

```
console.log('...');
return null;
```

You are also not return-ing in all possible situations. I'd also add a `return null;` at the end just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your code in render() with a div:

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {if (this.props.hasErrored){
        return console.log('sorry there was an error');
      }else if (this.props.isLoading){
        return console.log('Loadings...');
      }else {
        if(this.props.data.length){
          return (
            <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
          );
        }
      }
   </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, inside `render` method, if `this.props.hasErrored` results in true then the component will return `undefined` with printing a console message but react Components should return `JSX` or `null`, So you can do:

```
render() {
    if (this.props.hasErrored){
        console.log('sorry there was an error');
        return null;
    }else if (this.props.isLoading){
         console.log('Loadings...');
         return null;
    }else {
        if(this.props.data.length){
            return (
               <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
            );
        } else {
             return null;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: actually there should not be any case where `JSX` or `null` is not returned from `render` method

Comment: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `DataList`, expected `array`.

Comment: data is an `Object` so `Array.map` is causing this issue

Comment: what that data object looks like? somewhere it'll have an array i guess so, log that and check

Comment: `DataList.propTypes = {
    fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};`

Comment: Object { data: (187) […] }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179475/discussion-between-syed-sadaif-rizvi-and-suman-kundu).